# Silex/Symfony Security Firewall Access user token outside the secured area

Tags: php, security, symfony, silex

I use Silex and the SecurityProvider, my firewall :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
  'security.firewalls' => array(
    'user' => array(
      'pattern' => '^/user/',
      'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/connexion',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
        'default_target_path' => 'homepage_user'
        ),
      'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/user/deconnexion')
      ...
      )
    )
  ));
```

It works ! But I didn't find any way to access to the user object in the template, the symfony synthax doesn't work :

```
{{ app.user }}
```

So I add a new global in Twig like this :

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
  $token = $app['security']->getToken();
  $user = ($token === null) ? null : $token->getUser();
  $twig->addGlobal('user', $user);
  return $twig;
}));
```

It works but not outside the secured area: $token is null

My question is simple : How can I access to the user outside of the secured area ?

Thank you

**EDIT:** I tried to add a firewall with anonymous = true, like this :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
  'security.firewalls' => array(
    'user' => array(
      'pattern' => '^/user/',
      'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/connexion',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
        'default_target_path' => 'homepage_user'
        ),
      'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/user/deconnexion'),
      ...
      ),
    'unsecured' => array(
      'anonymous' => true
      )
    )
  ));
```

But it doesn't work, outside of the secured area, when the user is logged, the token is "anon."

Comment: But what are you want to do with a user outside of a secured area? I mean, there you can't assume that, you will have a user always.

Comment: It's simple, on my homepage, I want different links if you are logged (link to the user homepage) and if you're not (link to register, to login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But then what you need to do, is put that page under the firewall too.
Change the firewall setting so / is the firewall, and add ACL so anonymous can also enter to /. Then you can have there user data.

Where you load in your header data, you check that the user is authenticated or not, cause this is the main thing, `isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')` and depending on the result, you will include different template file.

Answer (score 0):

The user information is only available in secured areas, to get access also outside of these areas you must allow anonymous users as [described in the documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#allowing-anonymous-users):

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'unsecured' => array(
    'anonymous' => true,

    // ...
),
```