# Accessing app.user in unsecured area, silex

Tags: symfony, silex

I have this configuration for firewall :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
     'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/admin',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/#login',
                'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
            )
        ),
    'unsecured' => array(
            'anonymous' => true,
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
        ),
    ));
```

and also this for security.rules :

```
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    array('.*', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
);
```

I see this answer : [Silex/Symfony Security Firewall Access user token outside the secured area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20166817/560561) 
But the problem is, I can not access the app.user in "/" page and is_granted (in twig) always return false to any input.

I don't know if the ACL mentioned in that answer is something else (other than the access_rules) or I do something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a user (token) is only accessible within the firewall that logged it in. So as long as you are within `/admin` part of your site you would have access to the `app.user`, but not within the "unsecured" firewall.

To have the behaviour you are looking for, you need to have one overall/sitewide firewall with the pattern of `^/` and then use access rules to restrict access to `/admin`.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/#login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
        )
    ),
));

$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    array('^/', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
);
```

So a brand new user to your site would be immediately authenticated anonymously, until they login with a role that allows them to access `/admin`.

It's also worth noting that if you were to have your login form within admin area, as something like `/admin/login`. Them you would need to add an anonymous access rule for the login URL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but it always force users to login.

Comment: Ok, you will more than likely need to add ```'anonymous' => true```, I've edited my answer. Let me know if this works better for you.

Comment: I've also switched the access_rules ordering as I believe it matches the first it comes to.

Comment: Thank you! now every thing is OK.

Comment: Where should that `anonymous access rule` be placed in `security.access_rules`? I mean the order according to other rules in example