# Silex - access to user outside a secured area

Tags: symfony, security, silex

I have set up a secured area in my Silex website. I need to display the username in the header when the user is connected or a link to the login form if the user is not connected.
But when the user is on a page not secured (outside the firewall), the `app.user` is not defined.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909574/accessing-app-user-in-unsecured-area-silex) solution, but it does not work.

Here my security configuration:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'account' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/account',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/account/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
        'unsecured' => array(
            'anonymous' => true,
        ),
    )
));
```

And here my header where I'm displaying the username:

```
{% if app.user %}
    {{ app.user.username }}<br />
        <a href="{{ path('account') }}">Mon compte</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ path('login') }}">se connecter</a><br />
        <a href="{{ path('signup') }}">créer un compte</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend firewall to all application by modifying `pattern` to `^/` and allow anonymous access `'anonymous' => true`. Paths that should be secure specify in `security.access_rules`

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'account' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
            'anonymous' => true,
        )
    )
));

$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/account', 'ROLE_USER', null)
);
```

User method `getRoles()` should return role `ROLE_USER` that means that user has access to all paths from `security.access_rules` with role `ROLE_USER`.

```
class User implements \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface
{
...
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array(new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role('ROLE_USER'));
    }
...
}
```